# How can I disable this automatic debugger attached to my VScode terminal?

Tags: node.js, vscode-debugger

I get this popup every time I try to start a node process in VS CODE terminal
[image]

I tried searching in settings but couldn't find that particular setting. I found some of the js debugger settings but none of them were use to me.

Comment: Did you add break points in any of the files?

Comment: no i haven.t added any breakpoints